# What mechanism does git use to find its repository?

Tags: linux, git

I have several git repositories. One of these is in *$PATH*. Today, I accidentally moved to a directory that I thought had a git repository, but did not have one.

`cd <another_directory_without_.git>`.

So, when I entered `git status`, the output was confusing.

It appears git found the repository in *$PATH*, so in this case, git found the  repository in *~/bin*, which is in my *PATH*.

Does git search for repositories by looking in $PATH, or is there another search mechanism at work?

Comment: It goes up a level until it finds a .git, or it's run out of levels to go up. It has nothing to do with $PATH.

Comment: `git` doesn't look for repositories using `$PATH`, but it does have ways. A bit too long to copy here, but look for "Environment Variables" in the git manpage. It may be faster to search your own environment for variables starting in GIT_

Comment: These look like answers to me, so hopefully you'll answer the post. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you insist...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find a definitive reference for the actual details, but we can infer most of it from [the documentation to the git repository variables](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/#_the_git_repository).

Git looks for its a repository, by order of preference:

- in a directory provided by the `--git-dir` argument
- in a directory provided by the `GIT_DIR` environment variable
- in subdirectory `.git` or the current directory
- in subdirectory `.git` of an ancestor directory.  Environment variables `GIT_CEILING_DIRECTORIES` and `GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEMS` set a few constraints on that.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [`git(1)` manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html), Git goes like this when it looks for its object store:

1. If the "--git-dir" command-line option was specified its value is used to locate the repository.
2. If the `GIT_DIR` environment variable is available and set  its value is used to locate the repository.

   Note that in both of these cases no search/heuristics is done.
3. Otherwise Git tries to figure out if the current directory is *the* repository — in case it's a bare repository which has no work tree.

   The logic it uses to carry out this task is explained [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7aa67f62c7cc0f5771dffe58c3234b6940d35a5d/setup.c#L262).  To cite it:

   Test if it looks like we're at a git directory.
   We want to see:

   ```
   - either an objects/ directory _or_ the proper
     GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY environment variable
   - a refs/ directory
   - either a HEAD symlink or a HEAD file that is formatted as
     a proper "ref:", or a regular file HEAD that has a properly
     formatted sha1 object name.
   ```
4. Failing that, Git tries to find a directory named ".git" in the current directory.

   If it succeeds, it uses the test from the previous step to verify if it's really what it was looking for.
5. If it fails, it ascends one level up — to the parent directory and tries again.

   The last two steps are carried out until `/` on POSIX-like systems or the root of the drive — on Windows is hit (and hence there's nothing to ascent).  By default, Git also won't cross the boundary of a filesystem of the current directory.

As you can see, no `$PATH` is involved: this directory is used only to look up executable programs, and Git has no business with it.